# Where is the relation $ds/dx=(1+y_1)^{1/2}$ coming from?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading Wardle's Differential Geometry, here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

My doubt is in the following excerpt:

> [image]

**Question:** Where is the relation $ds/dx=(1+y_1)^{1/2}$ coming from?

Comment: Typo with $ds/dx=\sqrt{1+y_1^2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $s$ is the arc length of the curve,
$$\delta s=\sqrt{\delta y^2+\delta x^2}.$$
[image: illustration of delta s, y, and x]

In the limit as $\delta x\to0$,
$$
{ds\over dx}=\sqrt{1+\left({dy\over dx}\right)^2}
$$